# How to resolve 'Unable to import 'pytest'pylint(import-error)' in Hackerrank Web IDE

Tags: pytest, python-import, pylint

I am trying to solve hands-on training on PyTest in Hackerrank. I want to import the pytest module for the same. But when I type 'import pytest', I get this error - 'Unable to import 'pytest'pylint(import-error)'. I installed pylint using the terminal in Hackerrank, but it still shows same error. I am not sure if I need to change the pylint path anywhere, but if so, I don't know where. I am not able to complete the assessment because of it. Any insights to resolve the issue will be helpful [image of web ide with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP7ru.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your dependencies (pytest) installed alongside pylint in the environment that your IDE is using for pylint. Which means you probably have to install 'pytest' from inside your IDE. The sys.path modification where you're adding the current directory to the sys.path, in your screenshot might be a sign that the IDE is mis-configured if the code does not work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+shift+p then type pylint in search bar then click on enable/ON.After this run the code your issue is resolved.